# Unable to create react app using create-react-app showing e404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

Hey everyone I am new to development and recently started react.
when I am creating my react app it showing error in my terminal.

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/eslint@https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/eslint/-/eslint-8.4.4.tgz' is not in this registry.        
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sweta\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-30T19_09_57_337Z-debug-0.log
```

I don't know what to do earlier I have created react apps but they didn't show the problem but now every react app is showing this problem.

I have Installed hardhat twice in a local folder I think after then this problem started.

I have also tried npm install -g create-react-app
then I am getting 2 high severity vulnerabilities